# Migrating MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010 giving the error “Invalid Object Name sites”

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise, publishing

I am migrating SharePoint 2007 publishing site to SharePoint 2010. These are the steps I have followed

```
1. Backup the content database from the SP2007 machine.
2. Restore that database in sql server 2008 (SP2010 machine).
3. Create a new web application in SP2010 and create a site collection type of publishing template.
4. I have run the following stsadm command for adding the content database to the web application
```

stsadm -o addcontentdb -url http://testsite -databasename WSS_Content_test

But I am getting the **Invalid object name sites** error. Could anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be creating a site collection of publishing type template. When you attach the upgraded db, the process will automatically create the root site collection.
And use powershell commands instead of now obsolete stsadm commands.
Refer here - http://technet.microsoft.com/hi-in/library/cc303436%28en-us%29.aspx